# IRQ Double Faulting

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, osdev

I have a problem, with the making of my first driver(PIT). The problem is clearly explained in this viedo i recorded earlier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjvTtVbaics&feature=youtu.be  . Let me show my timer driver first:

timer.c++:

```
#include "timer.h"

/* This will keep track of how many ticks that the system
*  has been running for */

typedef void(*regs_func)(struct regs *r);


static int32_t timer_ticks = 0;

extern void install_handler_irq(int irq, regs_func handler);


/* Handles the timer. In this case, it's very simple: We
*  increment the 'Timer::timer_ticks' variable every time the
*  timer fires. By default, the timer fires 18.222 times
*  per second. Why 18.222Hz? Some engineer at IBM must've
*  been smoking something funky */
void timer_handler_driver(struct regs *r)
{
    /* Increment our 'tick count' */
    timer_ticks++;

    /* Every 18 clocks (approximately 1 second), we will
    *  display a message on the screen */
//    if (timer_ticks % 18 == 0)
//    {
        printf("One second has passed\n");
//    }
}

Timer::Timer()
{
}

/* This will continuously loop until the given time has
*  been reached */
void Timer::timer_wait(int ticks)
{
    unsigned long eticks;

    eticks = timer_ticks + ticks;
    while((unsigned)timer_ticks < eticks);
}

void Timer::install_timer()
{
    install_handler_irq(0, timer_handler_driver);
}

/* Sets up the system clock by installing the timer handler
*  into IRQ0 */
Timer::~Timer()
{

}
```

and here is my irq c++ code:

irq.c++:

```
#include "irq.h"

#define PIC_MASTER_CONTROL 0x20
#define PIC_MASTER_MASK 0x21

#define PIC_SLAVE_CONTROL 0xa0
#define PIC_SLAVE_MASK 0xa1


typedef void(*regs_func)(struct regs *r);


/*Get all irq's*/
extern "C" void irq0(void);
extern "C" void irq1(void);
extern "C" void irq2(void);
extern "C" void irq3(void);
extern "C" void irq4(void);
extern "C" void irq5(void);
extern "C" void irq6(void);
extern "C" void irq7(void);
extern "C" void irq8(void);
extern "C" void irq9(void);
extern "C" void irq10(void);
extern "C" void irq11(void);
extern "C" void irq12(void);
extern "C" void irq13(void);
extern "C" void irq14(void);
extern "C" void irq15(void);


extern void panic(const char* exception);

regs_func irq_routines[16] = {

         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    };

    static PORT::Port8Bits p8b_irq;
    static SerialPort sp_irq;

    //Basically a declaration of IDT_ENTRY in 
    //idt.c++
    struct idt_entry {
        uint16_t base_lo;
        uint16_t sel; // Kernel segment goes here.
        uint8_t always0;
        uint8_t flags; // Set using the table.
        uint16_t base_hi;
    }__attribute__((packed));

    //Get the Exact IDT array from idt.c++
    extern struct idt_entry idt[256];

    static inline void idt_set_gate(uint8_t num, void(*handler)(void), uint16_t sel,
                  uint8_t flags) 
    {
        idt[num].base_lo = (uintptr_t)handler >> 0 & 0xFFFF;
        idt[num].base_hi = (uintptr_t)handler >> 16 & 0xffff;
        idt[num].always0 = 0;
        idt[num].sel = sel;
        idt[num].flags = flags;
    }

    IRQ::IRQ(){}; 
    IRQ::~IRQ(){};

    /* Normally, IRQs 0 to 7 are mapped to entries 8 to 15. This
    *  is a problem in protected mode, because IDT entry 8 is a
    *  Double Fault! Without remapping, every time IRQ0 fires,
    *  you get a Double Fault Exception, which is NOT actually
    *  what's happening. We send commands to the Programmable
    *  Interrupt Controller (PICs - also called the 8259's) in
    *  order to make IRQ0 to 15 be remapped to IDT entries 32 to
    *  47 */
    void IRQ::irq_remap()
    {

            // ICW1 - begin initialization
        p8b_irq.out(0x11,PIC_MASTER_CONTROL);
        p8b_irq.out(0x11,PIC_SLAVE_CONTROL);

        // Remap interrupts beyond 0x20 because the first 32 are cpu exceptions
        p8b_irq.out(0x21,PIC_MASTER_MASK);
        p8b_irq.out(0x28,PIC_SLAVE_MASK);

        // ICW3 - setup cascading
        p8b_irq.out(0x04,PIC_MASTER_MASK);
        p8b_irq.out(0x02,PIC_SLAVE_MASK);

        // ICW4 - environment info
        p8b_irq.out(0x01,PIC_MASTER_MASK);
        p8b_irq.out(0x01,PIC_SLAVE_MASK);

        // mask interrupts
        p8b_irq.out(0,PIC_MASTER_MASK);
        p8b_irq.out(0,PIC_SLAVE_MASK);
    }

    void install_handler_irq(int irq, regs_func handler)
    {
        printf(" \n Installer IRQ %d \n ", irq);
        irq_routines[irq] = handler;
    }

    void uninstall_handler_irq(int irq)
    {
        irq_routines[irq] = 0;
    } 




    /* First remap the interrupt controllers, and then we install
    *  the appropriate ISRs to the correct entries in the IDT. This
    *  is just like installing the exception handlers */

    void IRQ::install_irqs()
    {
        this->irq_remap();
        idt_set_gate(32, irq0, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(33, irq1, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(34, irq2, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(35, irq3, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(36, irq4, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(37, irq5, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(38, irq6, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(39, irq7, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(40, irq8, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(41, irq9, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(42, irq10, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(43, irq11, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(44, irq12, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(45, irq13, 0x08, 0x8E);
        idt_set_gate(46, irq14, 0x08, 0x8E);    
        idt_set_gate(47, irq15, 0x08, 0x8E);
    }

    /* Each of the IRQ ISRs point to this function, rather than
    *  the 'fault_handler' in 'isrs.c'. The IRQ Controllers need
    *  to be told when you are done servicing them, so you need
    *  to send them an "End of Interrupt" command (0x20). There
    *  are two 8259 chips: The first exists at 0x20, the second
    *  exists at 0xA0. If the second controller (an IRQ from 8 to
    *  15) gets an interrupt, you need to acknowledge the
    *  interrupt at BOTH controllers, otherwise, you only send
    *  an EOI command to the first controller. If you don't send
    *  an EOI, you won't raise any more IRQs */
    extern "C" void irq_handler(struct regs *r)
    {
        printf("IRQ Being Handled");
    }
```

and my irq.S:

```
.section .text
.extern irq_handler
.extern test_func

        .macro irq number
            .global irq\number
            irq\number:
                cli
               pushl $0
                pushl $\number
               jmp common_handler_irq
        .endm

common_handler_irq:
      # save registers


            pusha

       # call C++ Handler
           call irq_handler

       # restore registers
            popa
            iret

#TODO FOR LOOP
irq 0
irq 1
irq 2
irq 3
irq 4
irq 5
irq 6
irq 7
irq 8
irq 9
irq 10
irq 11
irq 12
irq 13
irq 14
irq 15
```

Before I start my github is here, so you can see my whole code: https://github.com/amanuel2/OS_Mirror .So what happenes basically is. As you can see on my timer.c++ if i have the if statements commented it prints One Second Passed and the errors on qemu(double fault), if i dont it dosent print anything and double faults. as you can see by the viedo: [url]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjvTtVbaics&feature=youtu.be[/url].  Help Would Be Appreciated!

### EDIT:

Sometimes it decides to just show the error message on qemu , and dosent say One Second Passed at all, or even the Divide by 0 error, and gives me this :

```
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x491019d0

EAX=00000000 EBX=00009500 ECX=00000700 EDX=0010159e
ESI=00000000 EDI=00109000 EBP=00107122 ESP=001031ee
EIP=001019d0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 49000000 0008ffff 00589a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00103114 00000017
IDT=     00102900 000007ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=001031ce CCO=ADDL    
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
make: *** [Makefile:56: qemu] Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried debugging this for a while now.

Another problem is that its changing.... Its not a stable error as you can see on viedo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHQE_vIu_wU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: As an aside: 18.22 Hz = 4.77 MHz (clock speed of the original IBM PC) divided by 2^18.

Comment: @duskwuff thats the problem?

Comment: Please tag assembly questions with the architecture.

Comment: @Dsafds No. You just expressed some confusion about that frequency in a comment, and I figured I'd explain it.

Comment: The PIT frequency register accept 16-bit value, which v = (1193180/freq). setting v=65535 makes 18.2Hz, sounds a good default. (No actually I don't suggest assume pit was in good state, especially it won't reset with soft-reboot - reinitialize it)

Answer (score 2):

First there are minor problems in your remap pic code:

```
    p8b_irq.out(0x21,PIC_MASTER_MASK);
    p8b_irq.out(0x28,PIC_SLAVE_MASK);
```

master -> 0x21(33) ~ 0x28
slave  -> 0x28 ~ 0x2f

As you may figure now, you actually intended to map master to 0x20~0x27. But since you have a common IRQ handler it didn't go fatal.

Now for the crash, let's trace how the IRQ is handled:

- since you saw a message once, it indicate your IDT is good
- the CPU jump to the label `irq0` (which followed by cli and two push)
- jump to `common_handler_irq`
- pusha
- invoke C rountine `irq_handler`, which basically done nothing.
- popa
- iret

If you look carefully on the stack, there are two push left and `iret` will just jump into whatever that value - but not the resume address.

That's how you get "Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM".

To fix it, adjust the stack accordingly before iret.

PS: also note that `irq_handler` was not called with proper arguments, *reg is bogus too.

Comment: fixed the error.. but dont understand the PS . not proper arguments?  *reg bogus?

Comment: `irq_handler` expects `reg` as first parameter ([esp+4] for x86/cdecl), but it is the value of edi from pusha. normally you would do pusha; push esp (esp points to the pusha block); call cfunc;...

Comment: Why do i need the esp as an arg?